# How to calculate the absolute difference from pairs of numbers using a hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am looking to convert an integer array into key-value pairs where each element is a value of the preceding element and a key to the subsequent element with the exception of the first and last elements.

Once I have the array converted into a hashmap, I need to calculate the gap between integers in the array. I am able to convert the array but am looking for a more elegant solution and still need to find the gap.

```java
public void calculateGap(int[] nums) {
    int l = nums.length;
    Map<Integer, Integer> dist = new HashMap<>();
        
    for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if(i != l-1) {
            int val = nums[i+1];
            dist.put(nums[i], val);    
        }
        if(i != 0) {
            int key = nums[i-1];
            dist.put(key, nums[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Input: [3, 6, 9, 1]
>
> Input as a hashmap: {3:6, 6:9, 9:1}
>
> Output: [3, 3, 8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: I'm wondering what the hashmap detour is for, when one can calculate the distance straight away.

```
public int[] calculateGap(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int[] dist = new int[nums.length - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        dist[i - 1] = Math.abs(nums[i] - nums[i - 1]);
    }
    return dist;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  In your approach, you have parallel arrays.  I kept the OP's approach, and added a function to compute gap "on-the-fly".

Comment: Certainly a simpler and more readable approach. I chose the hashmap initially because I had to further manipulate the k:v pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Why not something like this:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> calculateGap(int[] nums) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length - 1; i++) {
          result.put(nums[i], nums[i+1);    
    }
    return result;
}    
...
public static int gap ( Map<Integer, Integer> map, int idx) throws Exception {
  if (idx < 0 || idx >= map.size()) {
     throw new Exception ("index "+ idx " exceeds list bounds 0 .." + map.size() - 1);
  }
  return Math.abs(idx - map.get(idx);
}
```

Comment: Nice breakdown although we could do away with the index argument. I simply iterated through the map and calculated the absolute difference of each entry's value and its key.

Comment: I'm still unclear about 1) Why you chose a hashmap (I assumed so you could quickly look up a value in your original list), 2) exactly which information you did and didn't need to "persist" in some data structure (I assumed you only  needed to "remember" the original numbers: the 1st and 2nd for each pair).  I was also unclear what you were going to use the "gaps" for.  I assumed you probably just wanted to find the gap for a particular pair.  Or maybe you didn't need to "save" anything at all: just compute each gap in the original list, print each out ... then forget about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a hashmap is unnecessary. You can skip it altogether and just store the calculated gaps in an int[] or an ArrayList:

```
//using int[]
public int[] calculateGap(int[] nums) {
    int len = nums.length;
    int [] dist = new int[len-1];

    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        dist[i-1] = Math.abs(nums[i] - nums[i-1]);
    }
}

//using ArrayList
public ArrayList<Integer> calculateGap(int[] nums) {
    int len = nums.length;
    ArrayList<Integer> dist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        dist.add(Math.abs(nums[i] - num[i-1]));
    }
}
```

BUT If you absolutely want to use a Hashmap, this is how you can do it within a single loop:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> calculateGap(int[] nums) {
    int l = nums.length;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dist = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> gaps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int prev = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<l;i++) {
        prev = nums[i-1];
        dist.put(prev, nums[i]);
        gaps.add(Math.abs(dist.get(prev)-prev));
    } 

    return gaps;
}
```

Or with an int[] output:

```
public static int[] calculateGap(int[] nums) {
    int l = nums.length;
    Map<Integer, Integer> dist = new HashMap<>();
    int[] gaps = new int[l-1];
    int prev = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<l;i++) {
        prev = nums[i-1];
        dist.put(prev, nums[i]);
        gaps[i-1] = (Math.abs(dist.get(prev)-prev));
    } 

    return gaps;
}
```

Obviously, you don't have to use dist.get(prev) as you can just use nums[i], but I am assuming for some reason you want to use the Hashmap to get the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for populating the HashMap, as it doesn't require special edge handling:

```
for(int i=1; i<l;i++)
{
    dist.put(nums[i-1], nums[1]);
}
```

But if you don't want to store it as a hash map, you can do a running total for the dist by making a second array called out put and do this instead:

```
for(int i=2; i < l; i++)
{
    output[i-2] = Math.abs(nums[i]-nums[i-1]);
}
```

Only one iteration through the array, and it returns the same output as yours

Comment: I think, you got the index wrong, the upper bound should be l + 1 for the second loop, or you use <=